# Python extract after and before certain conditions

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to extract only what appears after '/g' and before the '+' or '?'

```
urls = ["https://www.google.com/es/g/Dmitry+Kharchenko?searchterm=isometrico",
       "https://www.google.com/es/g/Irina+Strelnikova?searchterm=isom%C3%A9trico",
       "https://www.google.com/es/g/ParabolStudio?searchterm=auto"]

for i in urls:
    print(re.findall(r'g/(.*)[\+|\??]', i))


['Dmitry+Kharchenko']
['Irina+Strelnikova']
['ParabolStudio']

Desired result:

'Dmitry'
'Irina'
'ParabolStudio'
```

Comment: Try `(?<=\/g\/)[^+?]+`, `(?<=\/g\/)` being a *positive lookbehind*.  [Demo(https://regex101.com/r/R2peEP/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use non-greedy pattern `.*?` which will match up to the first `+` or `?` it encountered instead of the last `+` or `?` in greedy case, i.e. `.*`; To match `+` or `?` with character class you can just do `[+?]`:

```
for i in urls:
    print(re.findall(r'g/(.*?)[+?]', i))

# ['Dmitry']
# ['Irina']
# ['ParabolStudio']
```